# Returning by value from a function - Why does it work?

Tags: c++, c, function, return, return-value

Following is a simple function definition that returns an integer

```
int myFunc()
{
    int localVar = 99;
    return localVar;
}
```

and it called in main as

```
int main()
{
    int y = myFunc();
    cout << y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This works as it is expected. I want to know why? 
`localVar` is a local variable and its value is allocated in stack. It goes out of scope as soon as the function ends. So, `localVar` would have gone out of scope in the call `int y = myFunc();` How/Why is it still able to return the correct value?

Comment: So what's the purpose of returning a value if it is as you think?

Comment: because of the return type of your function `int myFunc()`.  It allows you to pass back an int value.  The variable `localVar` is indeed out of scope in `main()`, but localVar is not being used there, `y` is.

Comment: the value is not returned in stack, but in register

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is returning a *copy* of the value – that's what "return by value" means.
`int y = myFunc();` will copy the bytes of the value from a temporary location used by the function invocation to your local variable.

It would only fail if you return the *address* of the local variable.

Comment: Re the last sentence: or a reference to the local variable.

Comment: "will copy the bytes of the value" -- nominally. Once the optimizer is done with it things might look different :-)

Comment: Even if you did return the address, it may not fail visibly. It would invoke undefined behavior, which could appear to work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are three things to be aware of here:

- The object `localVar`
- The return value of `myFunc`
- The object `y`

Yes, `localVar` goes out of scope at the end of `myFunc`. However, before that happens, its value is being copied into the return value of `myFunc` (that's what the `return` statement does). Then, this return value is being copied into the object `y`. It doesn't matter that `localVar` is now gone - you have a copy of it.

That's exactly what returning by value does. It copies the result of the expression in the `return` statement into a return value.

Answer (score 0):

`localVar` must not be generated on the stack. If a register is available it could be used also.

If it was in fact created on the stack then the value is copied to a register anyway on returning.

Comment: That's all nice and well, but a register is even more ephemeral than a stack slot.

Comment: @delnan i just wanted to point out that it is not necessary to use the stack for local variables.

Comment: A fine point in general, it just doesn't answer the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `return` type of your function: `int myFunc()`. It allows you to pass back an `int` value. The variable localVar is indeed out of scope in main(), but localVar is not being used there, y is, and when used as `y = myFunc()`, it accepts the int value returned.